# heroku django timestamps not converting to UTC

Tags: django, datetime, heroku, utc

I've got a Django app (running on Heroku with Postgres) with a simple form that contains a DateTimeField():

```
class Response(models.Model):
    '''
    Model serves to record a users response to a given question on a given
    questionnaire.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        default=None,
        db_index=True,
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=False,
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_index=True,
        help_text=(
            "Date on which question was answered."
        )
    )
```

From what I understand, my `date` field should get populated automatically with the current datetime

> For DateTimeField: default=timezone.now - from django.utils.timezone.now()
>
> -- [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

Furthermore, it should be a UTC timestamp

> If USE_TZ is True, this will be an aware datetime representing the current time in UTC.
>
> -- [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now)

My settings.py has

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

And I've got some middleware that sets **current time zone** to CST:

```
from django.utils import timezone
import pytz

class TimezoneMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):

        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone('America/Chicago'))
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()
```

I have some debugging print statements used right before the form submit [`print(now(), localtime(now()), get_current_timezone())`] to validate that `now()` is actually UTC.

When I submit my form I'm seeing:

> 2018-03-06T16:56:23.569311+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-03-06 16:56:23.569131+00:00 2018-03-06 10:56:23.569145-06:00 America/Chicago

however the database stores `2018-03-06 10:56:23`

How can I ensure that my submitted timestamps properly get converted to UTC?

Comment: postgres; I'm not determining the value; it's determined automatically since I'm using `auto_now_add=True`

Comment: Ah, good question. I'm using a database client (dbbeaver) to check what is stored; I changed its settings to also display the timezone offset for timestamps and now I'm seeing `2018-03-06 10:56:23-0600`; so it looks like the proper timestamp is being stored! Feel free to submit an answer along these lines and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however the database stores `2018-03-06 10:56:23`

I would look into that more carefully; depending on how you're getting that value, it may or may not be what's actually stored in the database. Database drivers (and of course Django itself) can change the timezone on the way from the database. Check the timezone of that value if it's coming through the database driver and you might find that you don't have a problem after all.

Comment: Depending on what database client you use, if you reformat your timestamp as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ` (note the **Z**) you'll be able to retrieve data with timezone data; use this to confirm it's exactly what you were expecting.